# What is the diffence between different read options in spark?

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading a csv file through following code:-

```
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .master("local[2]") \
            .getOrCreate()
```

Now there are four different options to read:

1. `df = spark.read.load("/..../xyz.csv")`
2. `df = spark.read.csv("/..../xyz.csv")`
3. `df = spark.read.format('csv').load("/..../xyz.csv")`
4. `df = spark.read.option().csv("/..../xyz.csv")`

Which option should I use ?

EDIT:-

Also, both `inferSchema="true"` and `inferSchema=True` are working. Can we blindly use any one?

Answer (score 8):

`2` and `3` are equivalent.

`3` allows for an additional `option(key, value)`  function (see `4`, or `spark.read.format('csv').option(...).load()`) that could allow you to skip a header row, or set a delimiter other than comma, for example.

```
def load(self, path=None, format=None, schema=None, **options):
        """Loads data from a data source and returns it as a :class`DataFrame`.

        :param path: optional string or a list of string for file-system backed data sources.
        :param format: optional string for format of the data source. Default to 'parquet'.
        :param schema: optional :class:`pyspark.sql.types.StructType` for the input schema
                       or a DDL-formatted string (For example ``col0 INT, col1 DOUBLE``).
        :param options: all other string options
```

`1` does not parse CSV, [it uses Parquet as the default format](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/readwriter.html#DataFrameReader.load).

I would suggest `inferSchema=True` to prevent typos in the string value

Answer (score 5):

2 is an allias for 3. 
1 reads by default parquet files.

For example:
spark.read.csv() just calls .format("csv").load("path")

```
  @scala.annotation.varargs
  def csv(paths: String*): DataFrame = format("csv").load(paths : _*)
```

It doesn't matter which one you are using.(2,3,4) As I said 1 read parquet by default.